# ASP.NET MVC 4 RC Web API ModelState error for optional url parameters which are nullable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to create a global valdiation attribute for my Web API. So I followed the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/video-custom-validation) and ended up with the following attribute:

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        var errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (var key in actionContext.ModelState.Keys.Where(key =>
            actionContext.ModelState[key].Errors.Any()))
        {
            errors.AddRange(actionContext.ModelState[key].Errors
                  .Select(er => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, er.ErrorMessage)));
        }

        actionContext.Response =
            actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
    }
}
```

Then I added it to global fitlers in the Global.asax:

`configuration.Filters.Add(new ValidationActionFilter());`

It works great with most of my actions but not as expected with actions that have optional and nullable request parameters.

For example:

I created a route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Optional parameters route", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}", 
    defaults: new { skip = UrlParameter.Optional, take = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And an action in my `ProductsController`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllProducts(int? skip, int? take)
{
    var products = this._productService.GetProducts(skip, take, MaxTake);

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, this._backwardMapper.Map(products));
}
```

Now when I request this url: `http://locahost/api/products` I get the a response with 403 status code and the following content:

```
[
{
    "Key": "skip.Nullable`1",
    "Value": "A value is required but was not present in the request."
},
{
    "Key": "take.Nullable`1",
    "Value": "A value is required but was not present in the request."
}
]
```

I believe this should not appear as a validation error since these parameters are both optional and nullable.

Have anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem you messed up your code between Web API and MVC, you should use **RouteParameter** from Web API instead of **UrlParameter** from MVC

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Optional parameters route", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}", 
    defaults: new { skip = RouteParameter.Optional, take = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But:

The default parameters of your route **skip** and **take** do not play any role for your route mechanism because you just use them in query string, not in route template. So the most corrective route should be:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Optional parameters route", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );
```

Comment: Good point but still it doesn't solve the issue here. Both parameters are "required" and have errors in ModelState dictionary despite they're nullable. Do you know of a way to mark an action parameter as not required?

Comment: As for your question, use optional parameters

Comment: I am sorry - I messed up something in my routes. Now it works prerfectly both with and without optional parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to avoid/suppress model validation for primitive types in GET request..

```
public class ModelValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid && actionContext.Request.Method != HttpMethod.Get)
            { ...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?